# constructing feature vector to learn cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, feature-extraction

Example:

Doc { 
  Citations: { 
      0: cite0, 
      1: cite1,
      2: cite2,
      ...
      n: citeN
 
    }
}

I am suppose to cluster documents base on the similarity of citations, but each document will have many citations. My confusion here is ...how do I construct the feature vector for the dataset in this case to feed it into my clustering toolkit.

I am thinking to let column be the citations, and the value to be 1 if that document has that citation.

ps. my background in machine learning is pretty weak - I am reading my lecture notes, but most doesn't touch on this kind of problems >< thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One simple way of constructing your feature vector would be to create Adjacency matrix (say A). The features are binary.

Each row will represent cited document and column will represent citing document. So, if `Document1` is cited by `Document3` only, element A(1,3)=1 and rest elements of the row are 0.

If you are dealing with too many documents, this might not be efficient way. If you have N documents, the matrix size is NxN.

If you are writing your own clustering algorithm, make it accept more compact forms (see Adjacency list instead).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was reading on weka they seem to have relational attributes but I guess, in normal cases, I would just use NxM matrices, where M is the long list of citations. and N being the list of documents